# Failed Network Error When Downloading Log File From Webmin File Manager

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-22.04, file-manager, webmin

Using Webmin File Manager to download apache logs inside the var/log folder
This is the log shown in webmin file manager. When I right click and click download
[Webmin File Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnyay.png)

What happens is, the downloaded file is showing as in the image
[Recent Downloads from Chrome Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YL1s.png)

When I open the link being downloaded its this link
`https://example.com:10000/extensions/file-manager/download.cgi?download=2&filename=apibeta%5Ferror%2Elog&path=%2F&overwrite_efiles=false&follow_symlinks=false`

My goal is to able to download the apache logs successfully. Im using Ubuntu server 22.04LTS

I tried changing the permissions to full read and write access.
Also tried downloading using the root user but when trying to download still no avail.

How can I download this log file from Webmin Filemanager successfully.